# AngularJs $compile finish / end event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Hi I would like to know,
if there is a way to get something like promise (i guess it will be postLink in this case) on $scope.
i an unanswered question here: [AngularJS: how to know when the $compile has finished?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19743143/angularjs-how-to-know-when-the-compile-has-finished) which is very similar to my question,

but i wonder if someone can help me understand how can i hook the postLink event:

i have the following code:

```
var compiledEl =
$compile("<link data-ng-repeat='stylesheet in injectedStylesheets' data-ng-href='{{stylesheet.href}}' rel='stylesheet' />");
head.append(compiledEl(scope));
```

so i don't know where to add `promise.resolved(true);`
cause i don't see the postLink. how can i know when the $compile comes to an end.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make yourself a directive:

```
app.directive('compileCallback',function(){
  return {
    priority: 1001, // make sure it's the last to run
    link: function (scope, element, attrs){
      scope.$eval(attrs.compileCallback);
    }
  }
});
```

Inside your template:

```
<link data-ng-repeat='stylesheet in injectedStylesheets' data-ng-href='{{stylesheet.href}}' rel='stylesheet' compile-callback="promiseResolve()" />
```

Comment: this is a good answer, BUT - you probably don't want to create an isolated scope for this directive, because then you force this directive to be the only one with isolated scope, on a specific html-tag. a better implementation will use the attrs.compileCallback to implement the same behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Based on angular documentation, it says:

`Directives with greater numerical priority are compiled first.`

So, I don't think setting this priority value here is correct with the intention that it'll be run last. Please correct me if I'm wrong though.

Although this directive will call the function when it's completed.

Also, I'd put a check to make sure `compileCallback` is set like:

```
if (angular.isFunction(scope.compileCallback)) {
   scope.compileCallback();
}
```